# Laravel Validate Moment.js Date

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, date-range, laravel-validation

I am trying to validate the date range in Laravel where the data is sent from my Angular Javascript.

Frontend Angular sends the date range using moment.js like this:

```
            var endDate = moment();
            var startDate = moment().subtract(29, 'days');

            var apiDateRange = {
                'startDate': startDate.format(),
                'endDate': endDate.format()
            };
```

In console, I can see that the date is posted like this:

```
endDate     2015-09-14T15:39:53+05:30
startDate   2015-08-16T15:39:53+05:30
```

I am trying to validate the date in Laravel. From reading the docs, I see that I need to use `date_format` for this. But I am getting the format wrong. This is what I have tried so far and are obviously wrong:

```
$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
   'startDate' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u"|required'
   'endDate' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d H:i:s.u"|required'
]);


// AND

$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
   'startDate' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"|required',
   'endDate' => 'date_format:"Y-m-d\TH:i:s"|required',
]);
```

I read the [php date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) doc and I am confused on putting together the `date_format` for this. Can someone kindly help me out here please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can't you pass as a date string like `2015-06-10 01:10:25` when formatting

```
var format_to = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss';

var apiDateRange = {
   'startDate': startDate.format(format_to),
   'endDate': endDate.format(format_to)
};
```

Plus i think its better to have validation like `'startDate' => 'required|date'`

Comment: I can try changing to date string. But after validation, laravel will be using this date in eloquent to get rows for that date range. At the moment, query works in the current date format. I will try and see if it works in date string format too without needing to parse it again using Carbon when used in query like `where('created_at', '>=', $startDate)`. Thank you for your input.:)

Comment: yes no prob:) , if your using datetime column then it will definitely work :)

Comment: sweet. thats great then. Thank you @K.Toress

Comment: glad if it helps :), cheerz

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question is.

I just found out shortly after posting my question that using the laravel `date` validation works instead of using the `date_format`. So this is what I have now:

```
$validator = Validator::make($postData, [
               'startDate' => 'date|required',
               'endDate' => 'date|required'
           ]);
```